# How do I set color of a H2 tag on div hover?

Tags: html, css

So guys I want to set a color of H2 inside of a divID:hover in css.

Is there a way to do this?

Btw I don't want to use Javascript for this.

```
#moto:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: green;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: You want to set the color of the `h2` when you `hover` over *only* the `h2`, or whenever you `hover` over the entire `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will apply to an h2 element any where inside the div on hover.

```
#divId:hover h2 { 
    style
}
```

Using the child combinator will apply only to direct children.

```
#divId:hover > h2 { 
    style
}
```

Comment: @АндрејЋосо glad to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some colors, you can manage as you need.

```css
#moto {

    border-color: blue;
    color: black;
    height:30px;
    background-color:gray;
}
#moto:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: green;
    color: green;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="moto">heading</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not that new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be

```
#moto:hover h2 { ... }
```